# Why default TXT DNS records have values "l|pl", "3|welcome", "v=spf1 include:mx.ovh.com ~all", "1|www.mydomain.com"

Tags: dns

I have domain registered in OVH.

My domain have TXT records:

```
TXT www.mydomain.com   "l|pl"                             3600 
TXT www.mydomain.com   "3|welcome"                        3600 
TXT mydomain.com       "v=spf1 include:mx.ovh.com ~all"   3600 
TXT mydomain.com       "1|www.mydomain.com"               3600
```

I would like to remove them but do not know if something will not be broken.

Why these TXT dns was set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is offtopic here as not related to programming, but it has already been asked and I replied to it at https://serverfault.com/a/940448/396475

In short:

Based on [this post at OVH community forums](https://community.ovh.com/t/a-quoi-servent-ces-entrees-txt-par-defaut/3627) in French, it seems to be automatically added when domain is created in order to display the default webpage.

PS: please do not obfuscate things badly. `mydomain.com` exists and is certainly not yours. In general providing real names is better. If really needed to hide things, use `example.com`. See RFC 2606 for details.